# Show '0 comments' text on posts.php page using Anchor CMS

Tags: php, html, anchor-cms

I'm using this PHP to show the comments on my homepage:

Functions.php

```
function tootsweet_article_total_comments() {
return Comment::where('post', '=', article_id())
      ->where('status', '=', 'approved')
      ->count();
 }
```

Posts.php

```
<?php if (tootsweet_article_total_comments() > 0) 
 {
   echo '<a href="'.article_url().'#comments">';
   if (tootsweet_article_total_comments() == 1) 
     echo ' comment';
   else
    echo tootsweet_article_total_comments().' comments';
   echo '</a>';
 }
```

?>

All is working perfectly, but when a post has 0 comments, no text is shown at all whereas I want it to say '0 comments'. I'm a bit of an amateur with PHP, so is there something I need to amend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by checking if the number of comments is greater then 0, but you don't do anything if the number of comments is equal to 0.

You'd need an else to your first check for comments, i.e.

```
<?php 
if (tootsweet_article_total_comments() > 0) {
    echo '<a href="'.article_url().'#comments">';

    if (tootsweet_article_total_comments() == 1) {
        echo ' comment</a>';
    } else {
        echo tootsweet_article_total_comments().' comments';
        echo '</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<a href='" . article_url() . "'>0 comments</a>";
}    
?>
```

n.b added brackets for readability and to make the logic clearer, feel free to remove if you prefer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. How do I make the '0 comments' a link, the same as if there are plural comments?

Comment: I've just noticed there's an issue when a post only has 1 comment. It causes all of the text in the post to become a link, as if the opening link for 'Comment' isn't closed?

Comment: That's because the closing ` echo '</a>';` is in the `else` statement. have updated the answer